# How to place a gif image in Label of a view in RCP application

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a `Lable(org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label)` in a view for which I've set an image which is a gif image,named ajax.gif
using `label.setImage();`
In this case image is shown without animation, is there a way do this(show animated gif)?

Answer (score 6):

SWT labels do not support this out of the box. But you can implement it yourself by using a separate thread to cycle through the images in a certain interval and set them on the label. There's an [official SWT code snippet](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet141.java) that will show you how to do it.